# Radiobox in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i m quiet new on using MVC3 applicaytion. recently i have been working on a website and i am using entity framework database first approach, where my code are generated automatically. But i wanted to use radio button so that user can choose their option instead of typign in textbox. Now the model of the page is(which is created automatically) :

```
    public int RID { get; set; }
    public string Contribution { get; set; }
    public string Topic_Relevance { get; set; }
    public string Significance { get; set; }
    public string Technique_Quality { get; set; }
```

I want to use radio box for Topic Relevence(e.g 0-20%, 21-40%, 41-60%, 61-80%, 81-100%) on view page and also want ot insert that selected value to insert into database. How do i do it ?

Help please ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't select a range with a radio button.  You can select a single value that represents that range though (0, 21, 41, etc..) You would also want Topic_Relevance to be an integer rather than a string.

If you do that, then it's relatively simple to do something like this:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Topic_Relevance, 0)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Topic_Relevance, 21)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Topic_Relevance, 41)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Topic_Relevance, 61)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Topic_Relevance, 81)
```

etc..  You would probably want to put lables on these to indicate the range to the users.

Comment: ok, if i use this way then how do i add the value (e.g 21, 41) into database ?

Comment: @Shaan If you have some logic that can choose radio box ranges (0-20%), then you should be able to use the same logic to convert your radio box value back into the original range.

Comment: @Shaan - the same way you add any other value into the database.  That's a very vague question.